# Run php script every x seconds using Cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I need to run a php script every x seconds.

x seconds are stored in mysql database .

the cron must now its time to work from database .

i know how to add cron job every one minute and other static time .

but this is new to me.

Comment: Why are you using "cron" when the task is more or less permanent

Comment: you can create/delete cron jobs from php script by using exec(), but I believe, in most cases, there're other better ways than doing it.

Comment: Mysql Schedule? PHP not even involved

Answer (score 0):

Don't need cron job or mysql scheduler. If job must be run in seconds interval use SLEEP function and rerun it again and again. [Documentation](http://php.net//manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: This answer is incomplete.